# java passes toString() to a method

Tags: java, generics, tostring

I have the following code

```
public class Mamman14 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

    public class SortedPair < E extends Comparable < E >> {
        E Max_Element;
        E Min_Element;

        public SortedPair(E FirstElement, E SecondElemnt) throws IllegalPair {
            int Compare_Result = FirstElement.compareTo(SecondElemnt);

            if (Compare_Result == 0) {
                Max_Element = null;
                Min_Element = null;
                throw new IllegalPair(FirstElement.toString(), SecondElemnt.toString());
            } else if (Compare_Result > 0) {
                Max_Element = FirstElement;
                Min_Element = SecondElemnt;
            } else {
                Max_Element = SecondElemnt;
                Min_Element = FirstElement;

            }
        }

        public E getFirst() {
            return Max_Element;
        }

        public E getSecond() {
            return Min_Element;
        }

        @
        Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s is bigger then %s.", getFirst(), getSecond());
        }

    }

    public class IllegalPair extends Exception {
        public IllegalPair() {
            super("Elements must be different!!");
        }

        public IllegalPair(String Element) {
            super("Elements must be different!! \n However they are equal to " + Element);
        }

        public IllegalPair(String Element1, String Element2) {
            super("Elements must be different!! \n However the elements are " + Element1 + "and" +
                Element2 + "and they are equal.");
        }

    }
}
```

It's a simple program that compares 2 elements and sets them in Max_Element and Min_Element accordingly.
I have two questions:

When I write `public class SortedPair <E extends Comparable<E>>` does that mean that SortedPair can receive only comparable elements which contains the compareTo method?

In the line `throw new IllegalPair(FirstElement.toString(), SecondElemnt.toString())` I create a new object using the toString() method of the elements, lets say the elements don't have a toString() method, what is being send?

Thanks.

Comment: It's best to ask *one* question per question.

Comment: Will do next time Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I write public class `SortedPair <E extends Comparable<E>>` does that mean that `SortedPair` can receive only comparable elements which contains the `compareTo` method?

It means that you can only use something that implements `Comparable` as the type argument, e.g.:

```
SortedPair<String> sp;
//         ^--- this must be a class that implements `Comparable`
//              or an interface that extends `Comparable`
```

...which in turn means you can use the methods defined by `Comparable` on any instances declared with your generic type `E`.

> In the line `throw new IllegalPair(FirstElement.toString(), SecondElemnt.toString())` I create a new object using the toString() method of the elements, lets say the elements don't have a `toString()` method, what is being send?

That will use the [`toString` from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), which is pretty boring. :-) This is what the docs say it will do:

> The `toString` method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Comment: So I guess there is no reason to overload IllegalPair with the first two constructors, right? Thanks.

Comment: @user2102697: If you're only ever going to construct `IllegalPair` using two strings, right, you don't need to first two constructors.

Answer (score 0):

all objects have a toString method inherited from Object class. the default implentation just display the classname and internal id.

When implementing comparable you should implent the compareTo method so that x.compareto(y) =-y.compareTo(x) so yes the compared object should also be a comparable

Answer (score 0):

If it comes to generic clause, indeed SortedPair would be of type of objects that inherit from Comparable.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question: `E exetends Comparable<E>` means that `E` must extend or implement `Comparable` (implement in this case, since `Comparable` is an interface). `Comparable` dictates that every class implementing it must have a `compareTo` method. So in short: yes, they must contain the `compareTo` method.

To your second question: every class that does not define a `toString` method will inherit the one from `Object`, which ususally looks something like: `your.package.YourClass@<somehex>`